# Tag filter remembered but not applied when going back in history

Tags: bug, tags

When going back in history with your browser, the tag filter is remembered but not applied.

1. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/tags
2. Write any word in the filter text box. (For example: xamarin)
3. Click any tag.
4. Go back to the previous page with your browser.
5. The filter text box still contains "xamarin", but the filter is not applied.